# Mnémoniques pour les faux amis et les mots qui s'écrivent de la même façon

Tags: faux-amis

Quand j’étais écolier je me rappelle qu'on apprenait quelques mnémoniques (dont voici [une liste](https://fr.wikibooks.org/wiki/Liste_de_mn%C3%A9moniques) sur Wikibooks) pour faciliter l'acquisition de certaines notions scientifiques ou tout simplement apprendre beaucoup d'informations sans beaucoup d'efforts. Par exemple, la fameuse phrase *"Napoléon Mangeait Allègrement Six Poulets Sans Clamser Après"* pour se rappeler facilement de la place des éléments du tableau périodique des éléments (en l'occurrence troisième période).

Il y a quelques jours cette question a été posée :

- [Similar words in English and in French, and counterexamples](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/11378/similar-words-in-english-and-in-french-and-counterexamples)

puis je suis tombé sur cette question :

- [False friends et Faux amis](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/1444/false-friends-et-faux-amis)

Je suis en train de chercher une phrase qui englobe les "falses cognates", les mots qui s’écrivent de la même façon alors qu'ils ont une signification différente, et qui se lit différemment en anglais et en français.
J'ai fait un petit essai mais il reste encore des mots purement "anglais" (càd ne sont pas des faux amis) dans la phrase:

> The sky might **pour** down and the **rime** will settle **on** : that's **dire** !
>
> We shall forget about our **habits** **as** going across the **pond** is to avoid

Les mots que j'ai pu regrouper ici sont : *pour*, *rime*, *on*, *dire*, *habit*, *as*, *pond*

Chacun de ces mots a un sens différent selon la langue choisie (français ou anglais), à titre d'exemple "pour" en anglais c'est un verbe qui signifie "verser" alors que "pour" en français est une préposition.
Le problème est que j'ai dû utiliser d'autres mots anglais pour les relier (de quoi donner un sens à la phrase) : l'idéal serait une phrase à 100% faux amis ...

Je sais bien que trouver une phrase qui contient l’intégralité des "faux amis" relève de l'impossible mais même les phrases courtes sont acceptées…

Je sais bien aussi que c'est excentrique — plutôt ludique — mais y a-t-il une phrase qui englobe au moins les "falses cognates" les plus communs ?

Comment: Si je comprend bien, tu veux un truc similaire à `Mais où est donc Carnior` ou `viens mon chou, mon bijou, mon joujou, sur mes genoux, et jette des cailloux à ce hibou plein de poux`?. La liste des gallicismes est très longue (je me souviens de 4 pages pleines à apprendre dans un cours d'Anglais enrichie..). Ainsi je ne crois pas qu'une telle phrase puisse exister. Ou plutot, bonne chance pour savoir par coeur une telle phrase!

Comment: J'avoue que c'est la première fois que je découvre le groupe Les Dales Hawerchuk,merci pour le commentaire mais il ne s'agit pas de gallicisme : en effet un gallicisme conserve presque tout de l'usage d'un mot y compris le sens,l'orthographe et même  les accents.les mots qui m’intéressent sont des mots comme "pour" ou "bout" :deux mots en anglais et en français ayant une étymologie et un usage totalement différents alors qu'ils s'écrivent de la même façon...

Comment: Cette question est plus [un début de discussion](http://french.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) qu'une question spécifique comme nous les aimons. Mais bon, attendons de voir. **Merci de ne pas répondre juste pour proposer une phrase : si c'est le seul contenu de votre réponse, éditez la [réponse existante](http://french.stackexchange.com/a/11417).**

Comment: @Gilles si je suis sur ce site c'est pour progresser ,moi et les autres . je comprends que cela parait pour certains comme une question "vague" mais parfois un "début de discussion" apporte plus aux utilisateurs qu'une question "précise"...je pense qu'on devrait voter dans meta.french.stackexchange.com pour plus de liberté à lancer des "débuts de discussion" ...Think out of the box !

Answer (score 2):

Dans ma recherche en profondeur sur internet, j'ai trouvé un [article fort intéressant](https://www.cairn.info/zen.php?ID_ARTICLE=LING_372_0101).

En voici un extrait :

> Il s’agissait donc de faire tout d’abord la liste des lexèmes qui, sémantiquement, n’ont strictement rien à voir dans une langue et dans l’autre : ils sont totalement faux amis (273 homographes). Le groupe suivant est constitué par les lexèmes partiellement " faux " amis (et donc également partiellement " bons " amis). Ils sont au nombre de 702). Enfin, par élimination de ces deux catégories, on aboutit à une liste de lexèmes totalement bons amis, c’est-à-dire n’ayant que le ou les mêmes sens dans les deux langues (3 221 homographes).

Avec quelques exemples de leur liste:

[image]

[image]

[image]

La suite à lire sur [le site de l'article source](https://www.cairn.info/zen.php?ID_ARTICLE=LING_372_0101).

Pour répondre à la question : **Non**, il est impossible de faire une phrase englobant les **1000** homographes anglophones-francophones.

Answer (score 1):

C'est difficile de faire des phrases complètes avec seulement des faux amis à l'orthographe identique, à cause du manque de « petits mots » (articles, prépositions, conjonctions). Bons à prendre (en se limitant à des mots raisonnablement courants) :

- articles français : seize, cent, ma, son, ta, ton
- articles anglais : a, an, four
- prépositions françaises : par, pendant, pour
- prépositions anglaises : as, but, for, on

Cela dit ce n'est pas sorcier non plus.

> Tout sale travail : dire seize grosses injures point fines pour blesser son terrible patron.
>
> Ma pie sent ton chat, vole loin.

> Don sensible if vain dresses on fur bras for a river or water venue.
>
> Morale: main bosses ride cars but a mute tenant pays coins on buses.

Faire une phrase complète serait une autre histoire.

> (Pays.) “Pour ours!” ≠ Pays pour ours.